# APEX: Return an object data based on Max Date

Tags: apex

I have two related Object: Opportunity and Approval__c (1 to many)
I would like for a specific Opportunity to be able to extract the Approval that was presented last

I tried the Query:

```
SELECT Id FROM Approval__c WHERE Opportunity__c = :Opp.Id AND Type__c = 'Investment_Committee' and date__c = Max(date__c)
```

I tried the query:

```
SELECT Id FROM Approval__c WHERE Opportunity__c = :Opp.Id AND Type__c = 'Investment_Committee' GROUP BY Opportunity__r.id
```

None of theme seems to work .. Coudl you give me a hand ?
please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating query based only on one opportunity you can just select one Approval with specific order:

```
SELECT Id FROM Approval__c WHERE Opportunity__c = :Opp.Id AND Type__c = 'Investment_Committee' ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fetch this information for more than one opportunity at a time, then you could accomplish this by using a parent-child subquery (left outer join). The subquery can have its own WHERE, ORDER BY, and LIMIT clauses, which is the thing that makes this possible with SOQL alone.

```
SELECT
    Id,
    (SELECT Id FROM Approvals__r WHERE Type__c = 'Investment_Committee' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM
    Opportunity
WHERE
    Id IN :opportunityIdsListOrSet
```

That `Approvals__r` bit in the subquery is the *child relationship name*. It's usually going to be the plural of the object name + "__r" (instead of "__c"). The [documentation on relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) goes into some more detail, and you can also get the child relationship name through Apex (using SObject describe information) or through something like [the workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) (which allows you to browse through SObjects and see their details in a UI).